# ClickOnce Deplyoment: No icon in start menu search results

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

When I deploy my ClickOnce application, the icon for it shows up fine on the desktop and in the start menu. However, if I search for my application in Windows 10, the result that comes up always has the "default" icon showing (see screenshot). Is there a way to ensure my icon shows up here, too?

[image: Screenshot of the search results]

Comment: I guess you have done so, but... have you checked for the "icon and manifest" section at the project's properties on Application-> Resources?

Comment: Yes, the icon is set correctly here, and it works everywhere except in the start menu search results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you ever deployed it to that system before without the updated icon?
If so, this may be because of the Windows Search cache.

One possible solution to [clear Windows start menu cache](https://superuser.com/questions/1264628/delete-search-cache-in-windows-10-search-finding-non-existent-old-programs).

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I verified this by installing my clickonce app on a VM which had been recently reset. The icon showed up fine in the search results. Thank you :)